# Pre-processing every item in an IQueryable<T> in LINQ to objects

Tags: c#, linq, iqueryable

Please have a look at the following code:

```
var list = new List<MyClass>();
...
var selection = list
    .Preprocess()
    .Where(x => x.MyProperty = 42)
    .ToList();
```

I want to implement `Preprocess` in such a way that it can process every item selected by the predicate that follows. So, if `list` contains thousands of object, I don't want `Preprocess` to process all of them, but only those that are selected by the `Where` clause.

I know this sounds like it would be better to move  `Preprocess` to the end of the query, but I have my reasons to do it that way.

Is that possible with `IQueryable<T>`? Or does it behave like `IEnumerable`, where the whole LINQ-to-objects pipeline is strictly sequential?

Comment: I would initially say that what you are asking is impossible, because a LINQ item like this never knows what comes next. A different way to write it would be: `var preprocessed = list.Preprocess(); var whereResult = preprocessed.Where(); var selection = whereResult.ToList();`. When listed that way you can see that any statement never has knowledge about the next statement.

Comment: Could you have the preprocess method take the selector predicate instead: Preprocess(x => x.MyProperty == 42)?

Comment: Out of interest, what are those reasons to not just put preprocess after Where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your purposes, `IQueryable` here is no different from `IEnumerable`, which is, as you said, purely sequential. Immediately after you invoke `Where()`, there's effectively no trace of the original "collection".

Now, you *could* theoretically do what you want, but that would require rolling "your own LINQ". `Preprocess()` could return some kind of `PreprocessedEnumerable`, all the custom operators would attach to it and the final `ToList()` will do the reordering of the calls.